# Michio Kaku: General relativity action is not bounded from below (?)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, string-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral

In p.9 of Michio Kaku book Introduction to Superstrings and M-Theory-Springer (1998), he said

> General relativity (GR) is also plagued with similar difficulties. The GR action is not bounded from below, because it is linear in the curvature. Thus, it may not be stable quantum mechanically.

My question is that how can GR not bounded from below (what did Michio Kaku mean?) if we also have the positive mass and positive energy theorem in GR, proven by various people like Schoen, Yau and Witten?

Answer (score 4):

The Ricci curvature $R$, the Lagrangian of the Einstein-Hilbert action, can take any value (positive or negative) and is therefore not bound from below. The quote is talking about the *action* of GR, which is just $S= \int R \sqrt{-g} d^4 x$, so this is what it's refering to. Positive mass/energy theorems are not related.